# UIPopoverController with UINavigationController change anchor point?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, anchor, uipopovercontroller

I have a custom UIPopoverController that has a view with UINavigationController in it. The UINavigationController is rigged so it allows dragging of the whole UIPopoverController around by touching the navigation bar. (draggable popover). 
Once the UINavigationController pushes a new view, the size of the popover changes in an animated fashion, and location of the popover returns to the anchor point where it was first shown, before being dragged with my custom navigation bar. (also animated) Is there a way to change the anchor point of the UIPopoverController while it is presented, so that it does not animate back to it's initial anchor location after a push to the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what a 'draggable popover' is, but for your issues on the size of the popover and its anchor location changing, here are my views,

use the `setPopoverContentSize:` method of the UIPopover to set the size of the popover before pushing the new view within the navigation controller.

the `presentPopoverFromRect:CGRect inView:UIView permittedtDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirection animated:BOOL` to set the location where the popover's arrow points to and in which direction.